# Source Tree - Uninstall Command Line Tools (stree)

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

How do I uninstall the Command Line Tools I installed when pressing 'Install Command Line Tools' in Source Tree? (OS X)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably execute this command at the command line: `rm /usr/local/bin/stree`. As far as I can tell, this is the only command line tool that gets installed.